# MYSQL - Finding row delta using date rows that include holidays

Tags: mysql, finance

I have a table that includes a field with dates (call it date) and a field with a cumulative running total (call it X) | call it table SAMPLE.

***My data in field DATE does not include weekends and holidays.

I can find the delta in the numbers from day to day by simply subtracting any chosen value in "X" and subtracting that from the row above.

Here's my current query:

```
select
date,
a.X - b.X as 'Daily Total'

from SAMPLE as a 
left join SAMPLE as b
on b.date = if(weekday(a.date) = 0 , a.date - interval 3 day, a.date- interval 1 day);
```

The problem is that the above values work until I hit dates with holidays. If Monday is a holiday, then the values return null because a.date - interval 1 day will not exist. What's the best way to go about solving the holidays issue?

the below are the current results:

```
+------------+---------------+
| date       | X             |
+------------+---------------+
| 2018-03-26 |     -40105.00 |
| 2018-03-27 |      28470.00 |
| 2018-03-28 |       5265.00 |
| 2018-03-29 |     -23010.00 |
| 2018-04-02 |          NULL |
| 2018-04-03 |     -24830.00 |
| 2018-04-04 |     -21970.00 |
| 2018-04-05 |      -9620.00 |
| 2018-04-06 |      36465.00 |
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What will be the correct logic if Monday is a holiday? Get it from Sunday? set it to zero?

Comment: If Monday is a holiday, get it from last Friday. Thanks for asking. To clarify, the date field is working days that exclude weekends and holidays. So basically if Monday is a holiday then I want a.date (Tuesday) to subtract from b.date (Friday).

Comment: so far I have this "b.date = if(weekday(a.date) = 0 , ifnull(a.date - interval 3 day,a.date - interval  4 day), ifnull(a.date - interval 1 day,a.date - interval 4 day))
" but I'm still getting the Null values for some reason....

Comment: You cannot subtract by 4 since Friday might be a holiday as well. Will work on this.

Comment: That's a good point, You're awesome, Thank you!

Comment: I have an answer so pls test it if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will sort the table by date then assign a sequence or series of numbers from 1 to n. I will then subtract the value of current row from the previous row except the first row. For first row, i will copy the value X.

```
select rnk2.`date`, 
case when rnk1.r1=1 and rnk2.r2=1 then rnk1.X else rnk2.X-rnk1.X end as 'Daily Total'
from (
  select `date`,X,@r1:=@r1+1 as r1
  from  samples, (select @r1:=0) a 
  order by `date` ) rnk1
inner join 
  (select `date`,X,@r2:=@r2+1 as r2
   from  samples, (select @r2:=0) b
   order by `date`) rnk2
on (rnk1.r1=1 and rnk2.r2=1) or (rnk1.r1+1=rnk2.r2) 
order by rnk2.`date`
```

Comment: you sir @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ are a wizard. Yes that worked great! Thank you so much!

Comment: good to hear that. Please press the check button across my answer to accept it.

Comment: So this works, but I can't create a view out of it. Back to my other example previously done do you know why "b.date = if(weekday(a.date) = 0 , ifnull(a.date - interval 3 day,a.date - interval 4 day), ifnull(a.date - interval 1 day,a.date - interval 4 day)) " still creates a null value?

Comment: because I can't create a view out of it, I'm still looking for an answer. In my head, logically, "b.date = if(weekday(a.date) = 0,ifnull(a.date - interval 3 day,a.date - interval 4 day),a.date - interval 1 day)" THIS makes sense. But I'm still getting the NULL values. Why is that?

Comment: Let me see the error you are getting on creating a view out of the query. quote: "but I can't create a view out of it"

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting Error Code: 1351. View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter

Comment: create another Question, paste your code (create view), put the error message then I will work on it.  This is not related to the query anymore and should be handled via a separate question/answer

Comment: Thanks Anonymous. I posted my question with the title " MySQL error 1351 Can't Create a View"

Comment: I answered your question about creating the view. please check it.